# One of my ASP.NET pages takes ages to load

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently working on an Activity Input page where employees can put the amount of hours they've put in in a certain project per day - but this page takes a lot of time to load!

Here's where it takes time:

```
public bool ExistUserActivity(int iYear, int iMonth, IEnumerable<string> sDays, int iProjectId, string Login)
{
    bool strRet = false;
    try
    {
        foreach (string s in sDays)
        {
            string[] values = s.Split(' ');
            string strQuery = "SELECT ProjectId FROM UserActivity WHERE CalendarDate = '" + (new DateTime(iYear, iMonth, int.Parse(values[1]))).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + "'"; //We 2 donne [0] We et [1] 2
            strQuery += " AND ProjectId = " + iProjectId + "";
            strQuery += " AND Login = '" + Login + "'";

            OleDbDataAdapter mDB_DataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(strQuery, m_strConnectionString);
            DataSet mDB_DataSet = new DataSet();
            mDB_DataSet.CaseSensitive = false;
            mDB_DataAdapter.Fill(mDB_DataSet, "UserActivity"); //It seems to take time after this
            strRet = (mDB_DataSet.Tables["UserActivity"].Rows.Count > 0);

            mDB_DataAdapter = null;
        }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }

    return strRet;
}
```

Does anyone have any idea where the problem could come from and how to solve it?

Comment: You are executing a SQL query for every sDay in the enumerable.  If you have more than a few items in that enumerable, this could easily cause a delay - especially if the SQL server is on a different machine.

Comment: Oh I see, this is not my source code so I was wondering (first year comp. sci. student on an internship). There probably isn't enough information to find a faster way to do it, is there?

Comment: and fix the sql injection while your at it

Comment: SQL injection? From what I have just read it's a security issue, I'm new to it so I'll look into it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be multiple reasons of low performance. Here are some (most evident):

1. Ensure your table `UserActivity` has index with `CalendarDate`, `ProjectId`, `Login` columns included. If such index is missing and amount of data is considerably large - it could take a lot of time for sql server to select data.
2. If you really just checking if there any records met your criteria or not - there is no need to query all the data from server to client. It will be enough to change your query to `SELECT count(ProjectId) FROM UserActivity WHERE CalendarDate...` and calculate this rows count on server without getting all the data to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Try looping and spliting sDays first, but only load into a list value[1]. Build all of your dates and then execute your SQL for those dates. Also you could execute the SQL in a SPROC.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is taking time because you travelling alot to database to get data using foreach loop.
Do this:
Get all data in one go: 
Query database to get projectId,CalendarDate and store them in collection object.
Now using foreach loop query the collection object and look for date values.

E.g.

```
 public bool IsExists(int iYear,int iMonth)
        {
            bool check = false;
            string allDays = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 24";
            try
            {
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["aConn"].ToString());
                if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select ProjectId,CalendarDate from UserActivity where YEAR(CalendarDate) = " + iYear + " and MONTH(CalendarDate) = " + iMonth + "");
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> allValue = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
                if (reader != null)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        allValue.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(reader[0].ToString(), reader[1].ToString()));
                    }
                }
                string[] strSplit = allDays.Split(new char[] {' '});
                foreach (var s in strSplit)
                {
                    string _currentDate = Convert.ToDateTime(string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", s, iMonth, iYear)).ToShortDateString();
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kv in allValue)
                    {
                        if (_currentDate == Convert.ToDateTime(kv.Value).ToShortDateString())
                        {
                            check = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            return check;
        }
```